# Apollo File Upload Mutation always returns 404

Tags: express, networking, graphql, apollo

I am currently working on my first Graphql API using Apollo Express.
Everything works perfectly fine, except the file upload.

As per the Apollo documentation, I changed the Apollo client to

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: createUploadLink({
        uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    //typeDefs
});
```

on the server side, I applied the graphqlUploadExpress middleware by using

```
app.use(graphqlUploadExpress());
app.use('/static', express.static("./images"));
server.applyMiddleware({app})
```

I then created the file type and mutation in my `typeDefs`:

```
 scalar Upload

 type File {
        filename: String!
        mimetype: String!
        encoding: String!
        url: String!
 }
type Mutation {
 singleUpload(file: Upload!, vacId: String!, index: Int!): File!
}
```

The resolver then looks like this:

```
import {GraphQLUpload} from "graphql-upload"
---
Upload: GraphQLUpload,
Mutation: {
   singleUpload: async (parent, {file, vacId, index}) => {
   const {createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding} = await file;

            // See https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams
            const stream = createReadStream();

            //name, unter der die Datei gespeichert wird
            const nameToBe = `${vacId}-${index}.${filename.split('.').pop()}`;

            //ort, unter dem die Datei gespeichert wird
            const location = path.join(__dirname, `../images/${nameToBe}`)

            //schreibt die Datei ins fs
            const out = createWriteStream(location);
            stream.pipe(out);
            await finished(out, (err) => {
                err && console.error("Stream failed.", err)
            }
            return {filename, mimetype, encoding, url: `http://localhost:4000/static/${nameToBe}`};
   }
}
```

The interesting thing now is that I can use the mutation without a problem using altair
[image: altair client]
However, if I want to use the mutation from my react frontend with the following code:

```
const UPLOADIMAGE = gql`
    mutation($file: Upload!){
        singleUpload(file: $file, vacId: "testInput", index: 2){
            url
        }
    }
`
 const [uploadImage, {data, loading, error}] = useMutation(UPLOADIMAGE, {
        onCompleted: data => console.log(data),
    })

return (
<Dropzone onDrop={acceptedFiles => uploadImage({variables: {file: acceptedFiles}})}>
                                        {({getRootProps, getInputProps}) => (
                                            <section>
                                                <div {...getRootProps()}>
                                                    <input {...getInputProps()} />
                                                    <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </section>
                                        )}
                                    </Dropzone>
)
```

I get the following error indicating that the mutation is somehow not there
[image: console]

Comment: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec